# QlikView runs BodyOnLoadFunctionNames callbacks too early - why?

Tags: javascript, qlikview

I have a problem with QlikView in the browser: I have a listbox and try to access it using an initialize script.

The script is registered by using the [InitWorkbench](http://qlikcommunity.s3.amazonaws.com/misc/symbols/Qv.html#InitWorkBench) function, using its `BodyOnLoadFunctionNames` parameter. So far, this works, and the initializer is run at startup.

Inside the initializer I try to do the following:

```
var doc = Qv.GetCurrentDocument();
var listbox = doc.GetObject('LB01');
```

Afterwards, when I have a look at `listbox.Type`, unfortunately it is `undefined`. If I delay execution of this query, it correctly says `LB`, hence apparently the query works - but only when it is executed delayed.

So, obviuosly there's a timing problem, and it seems as if the initializer runs too early (or I am doing something wrong).

Can anybody point out what the solution is (or give me a hint on what I am doing wrong)?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found the solution: The internal update function did not run yet, and all the values are only available once this function ran, so you need to provide a callback to the call to `GetObject` (that gets called after the update function):

```
var doc = Qv.GetCurrentDocument();
var listbox = doc.GetObject('LB01', function () {
  console.log(listbox.Type); // => 'LB'
});
```